# How to hide "Events emitted during test" in truffle test?

Tags: truffle

When I run `truffle test` and my test fails - the log gets polluted with numerous messages which make difficult to read the error message itself and other debug outputs

```
 Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------
 Ownable.OwnershipTransferred(
      previousOwner: <indexed> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
      newOwner: <indexed> 0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57 (type: address)
 )
 IERC20.Transfer(
      from: <indexed> 0x8065F4c7b8c2bf53561af92D9DA2Ea022A0b28Ca (type: address),
      to: <indexed> 0x0d1d4e623D10F9FBA5Db95830F7d3839406C6AF2 (type: address),
      value: 119951999785389 (type: uint256)
    )

    Warning: Could not decode event!


... lots of other events ...

---------------------------

finally useful data
```

is there any way to hide events from the logs?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search in your node_modules for the lines that log the events. In my case, I used VSCode search (`ctrl + shift + f`) and searched "Events emitted during the test" in node_modules, then commented out the for loop logging everyting.

Comment: isn't there a more proper way to do this without tweaking node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to submit a ticket to truffle support: https://www.trufflesuite.com/community with the steps to reproduce. Do you have a public repo that you could share maybe?

Comment: I'm very confused with your answer, I don't think it's a bug at all, rather default feature of truffle which I yet to figure out how to turn off.